# Dependency injection in Angular Components like directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

Here's one thing I'm used to do with angular directives

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('login', ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: $templateCache.get('directives/login/login.html'),
        controller: 'LoginController as vm',
        scope: true
    };
}]);
```

I've grown very attached to using **Template Cache** to inject HTML content in my directive's template. Now with Angular 1.5 there's this new thing all the cool kids are using called **component()** which I'm giving a look to see if it's really good and I'm stuck at this very beginning part: how to inject things in the component itself (not in the controller)?

In this case you can see that I'm injecting into the *login* directive the $templateCache dependency. How would I rewrite this directive as a component? (keeping in mind my desire to use $templateCache over templateUrl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, In Angular 1.5 components, `template` property can be a function and this function is injectable ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)).

So, you can just use something like:

```
...
template: ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
   return $templateCache.get('directives/login/login.html')
}]
...
```

Few links from google search: [one](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/) and [two](http://www.codelord.net/2015/12/17/angulars-component-what-is-it-good-for/#comment-2518375683).

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 3):

MaKCblMKo 's answer is right, but remember that AngularJS will check the templateCache first before going out to to retrieve the template.  Therefore, you don't have to make this call in your directive or component.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.component('myComponent',{
    templateUrl: 'yourGulpPattern'
})
.run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('yourGulpPattern', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/osbnoebe/6/

Comment: It's not about putting content in there, I have a gulp task that minifies and 'put' every HTML file in Template Cache. I just needed to access the element so I could retrieve it's content.

Comment: That's cool, but what I'm trying to say is that if your gulp task does a 'put' then you still don't need to touch the $templateCache.  Just reference the url and it'll grab it from cache since it's already there.  My put example was just showing that it's already in cache.  In other words - imagine that the run function in my example is your gulp task... unless I'm still not understanding what you're saying.

Comment: Just reference the templateUrl and let angular pull it from the $templateCache for you.  I hope that's clearer.  I wasn't trying to show you how to put it in cache.

Comment: I tried your approach and I get a 404. In reality, my server is not serving a page in the path that would be required to use templateUrl, instead gulp just fills templateCahce with put with a predefined pattern that I can reach with $templateCache.get.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu you don't need to spend any more time on this.  I'm just very surprised this doesn't work.  I must not be understanding how your gulp script is filling the $templateCache then.  If it's filling it the same way as above `$templateCache.put(yourPredefinedPattern, template)` then by all accounts it should work.  In my fiddle, there is no file being served from the server either. https://jsfiddle.net/osbnoebe/5/  So long as your templateUrl matches the same pattern that gulp used to put it in the $templateCache then it should pull it out. Oh well...

Comment: I'm still addressing this because, although the answer I accepted does answer my question, your way is cleaner and I would prefer it. Fortunately, I ended up finding a totally unrelated issue that made me believe your method didn't work. Now I got it working just like you said and it's pretty neat.